# Undefined variable: data (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Aarogyam\resources\views\Home.blade.php)

Tags: database, laravel, foreach

I want to show the testimonials from the database to the Home page of the website. but it gives me the error $data is undefined. Please give me a solution...
**Route:-**

```
Route::get('Home','HomeController@getTestimonial');
```

**Controller:-**

```
function getTestimonial(Request $request)
{   
$data=DB::table('testimonials')->get();
if(count($data) > 0)
{           
 return view('Home',['data'=>$data]);
}
else
{
return view('Home');
}
}
```

View:-

```
<form action="Home" method="get">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<section class="testimonial-section" style="background: url(images/testimonials/1.jpg);">
<div class="container">
<div class="section-title text-center">
<h3>What Our
<span>Patients Says</span>
</h3>
</div>
<div class="testimonial-carousel">
@foreach($data as $value)
<div class="slide-item">
<div class="inner-box text-center">
<div class="image-box">
<figure>
<img src="storage/images/{{$value->photo}}">
</figure>
</div>
<h6>{{$value->name}}</h6>
<h7>{{$value->disease_name}}</h7>
<p>{{$value->review}}</p>
</div>
</div>
 @endforeach
<!--Slide Item-->
</div>
</div>
</section>
</form>
```

Comment: try to pass empty array in else return view('Home', ['data' => []]); as your blade is expecting a $data.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if your variable data arrives, with this:

```
@isset($data)
  @foreach($data as $value)
    <div class="slide-item">
    <div class="inner-box text-center">
    <div class="image-box">
    <figure>
    <img src="storage/images/{{$value->photo}}">
    </figure>
    </div>
    <h6>{{$value->name}}</h6>
    <h7>{{$value->disease_name}}</h7>
    <p>{{$value->review}}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
   @endforeach
@endisset
```

If data is null or empty, this piece of code dont run